# Watson speech to text is not matching custom words

Tags: speech-to-text, watson

I have added a customer word to watson for speech to text, but when I send in speech that matches a sounds_like entry I get the sounds like words and not the target word. I have my URL correct and I know the word is in the customization.

wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_BroadbandModel&customization_id=82a9efd0-b00c-11e6-9657-e53f14d32XXX

Comment: please describe the problem you are having in more detail

Comment: Not sure there is more detail I added a custom word with curl and a specific sounds like phrase. When I speak that phrase I get back the phrase and not the custom word

Comment: You need to provide details which exact requests you were using. To use words, you need to add corpus containing them as a custom corpora with https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/?curl#corpora_methods.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print here what the word, sounds_like and display_as values are for this word?  When you add a sounds-like, the word has to be said without pauses.  If you put a pause, then you might get the sounds-like words as separate words instead of the customized word.

Tony Lee (IBM Watson Speech group)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: curl -X PUT --user xxxxxxxxx:xxxxxx \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data "{\"sounds_like\": [\"and sauce\"]}" \
  https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/customizations/82a9efd0-b00c-11e6-9657-e53f14xxxxx/words/nzos

Comment: Please make sure that:

Comment: Please make sure that: 1) you have trained your model after adding words or corpora (by that I mean run the /train request - you can check that the status of the model is 'available', anything else means that the model is not trained) and 2) when you run the recognition, that you pass the customization_id in a query parameter.

Comment: Did you add this word as a word or as part of a corpus?  Usually you get better success if the new word is part of a corpus where there is some context around the new word.  Adding a word by itself doesn't guarantee that it will come out, especially if the word is short and sounds like other words.  If you can add examples of word usage in a corpus (and re-train) you have a better chance.